# How to display file on the screen in python?

Tags: python

How to display file on the screen in python ?

Note:

I don't want to open for read or write, i want to display the file on the screen,
like i double click on the file himself and it's open .

Thank you.

Comment: This is confusing like a txt file?

Comment: What kind of file? Do you want to open it in another program (as if it was double clicked) or print out the contents?

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'display'?

Comment: It would seem you want to open the file using the default program associated with the file, yes?

Answer (score 3):

Well in windows only executing the file works:

```
import os
os.system('c:/tmp/sample.txt')
```

on `SO` based in `UNIX` there is an `enviroment` variable named `EDITOR` and you can do something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.call([os.environ['EDITOR'], 'filename'])
except:
    try:
        subprocess.call(['gedit', 'filename'])
    except:
        subprocess.call(['nano', 'filename'])
```

Comment: For Windows you can use [os.startfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: @JonClements oh thank you for the recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('yourfile')
```

Or use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to open your file in any editor you know the path of.